# How to put a listview inside of a fragment in android?

Tags: java, android, listview, fragment

I'm trying to put a simple listview inside my fragment. I'm getting an error when I run it as is. I wasn't expecting it to work with the current code I have, but I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My code:

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends ListFragment {

ListView listView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LinearLayout theLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
    listView = (ListView)theLayout.findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    return theLayout;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Use an existing ListAdapter that will map an array
    // of strings to TextViews
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mStrings));
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}

private String[] mStrings = {
        "Action", "Adventure", "Animation", "Children", "Comedy", "Documentary", "Drama",
        "Foreign", "History", "Independent", "Romance", "Sci-Fi", "Television", "Thriller"
    };
```

}

my runtime error:

```
07-19 11:42:45.214: E/AndroidRuntime(19873): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 11:42:45.214: E/AndroidRuntime(19873): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{package/package.TabActionBarActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
07-19 11:42:45.214: E/AndroidRuntime(19873):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-19 11:42:45.214: E/AndroidRuntime(19873):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-19 11:42:45.214: E/AndroidRuntime(19873):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-19 11:42:45.214: E/AndroidRuntime(19873):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
```

Answer (score 7):

You should try calling `setListAdapter()` in the `onActivityCreated()` method.  This is because the Activity hasn't been completely created by the `onCreate()` method of a Fragment since the lifecycles of each are slightly different.

Here is a similar question: [Android Fragment onCreateView vs. onActivityCreated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041206/android-fragment-oncreateview-vs-onactivitycreated)

Answer (score 5):

A couple of problems in your fragment:

1. If you are using ListFragment, then in your XML layout, you must have a ListView that has id of 'android.R.id.list'.
2. Call your setListAdapter() method in onViewCreated() instead of onCreate(). This is because onCreate() is called first before onCreateView().