# NullPointerException findViewByID of a EditText inside a fragment from his parent activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, navigation-drawer

I have a problem here, I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when I try to set text inside an `EditText` placed in my *layout_fragment.xml*.

I'm using `findViewById(R.id.TextView)` on the fragment parent Activity in `onCreate()`.

The activity has drawer navigation implemented and the *layout_fragment.xml* belongs to a the first displayed fragment of it.

**Navigation.class**

```
EditText edt_nome;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navigation);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    edt_nome = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.home_nome);
    edt_nome.setText("someText");
}
```

The code is not much and its simplified because of a confidentiality agreement.

Comment: post `navigation.xml`

Comment: if edtitext is in fragment why not initialize it there??

Comment: possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653778/nullpointerexception-accessing-views-in-oncreate
 - in essence the `findViewById()` is too early and the fragment view is not yet attached to the activity

Comment: i have an asyncTask on the navigation.class making a connection with an api that populates an ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> and i cant send it to the fragment to set his components on the EditTexts, so it have to be on Navigation.class

Comment: you can send list to fragment

Comment: @laalto the code is after this method that attaches the fragment to the activity so i guess that's not the problem, but thanks anyway
'        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            // on first time display view for first nav item

            displayView(0);


        }'

Comment: bundles dont accept the object ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> @Raghunandan

Comment: @BrunoLorenço http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355787/how-to-pass-arraylisthashmapstring-stringfrom-one-activity-to-another. It should work in case of fragment also

Comment: @Raghunandan that will resolve it, but i dont know if it will work fine when i click the update button that is on the Options Menu and will re-populate the ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> object, because the intent extras are only reloaded when the fragment is restarted

Comment: @BrunoLorenço design is your problem but initialize edittext in fragment

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to access activity to early than it is created.

so move this code

```
    edt_nome = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.home_nome);
edt_nome.setText("someText");
```

to onActivityCreated,i think that should fix the issue
if not please post exception details.

Comment: What if I wanted to access the EditText in Fragment from Activity, I get a NPE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907625/why-is-accessing-textview-of-a-fragment-inside-activity-throwing-an-error

Answer (score 0):

You just cant edit any widget like that.
I suggest to handle with
**fragments** and implement
 *onCreateView()*

:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.FRAGMENT_LAYOUT, container, false);
        EditText et;
        et = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.EditText);
        et.setText("SomeText");
        (...)
      }
```

about the previous answer, take a look on this topic:

[Android Fragment onCreateView vs. onActivityCreated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041206/android-fragment-oncreateview-vs-onactivitycreated)

Answer (score 0):

If you have declared `<EditText>` in layout_fragment.xml then you must use  `setContentView(R.layout.layout_fragment);` to deal with that EditText