# Setup view inside onCreateView vs onActivityCreated

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am really curious about what is the best practice to setup views in a Fragment. This is what I have been doing ever since I started developing for android.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
    ListView listView = view.findViewById(...);
    listView.setAdapter(...);
    return view;
}
```

I have then read about the method `onActivityCreated` and read that I need to setup the view inside that and not `onCreateView` so I wrote my self some code to do the same

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
}

public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    View view = getView();
    if(view == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("View returned null inside onActivityCreated this shouldn't have happened!");
    }
    ListView listView = view.findViewById(...);
    listView.setAdapter(...);
}
```

I'm really curious what's the difference here? And which should be used? Which one does android recommend you to use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference and uses of onCreate(), onCreateView() and onActivityCreated() in fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929637/difference-and-uses-of-oncreate-oncreateview-and-onactivitycreated-in-fra)

Comment: @HarounHajem This isn't a duplicate, I am not asking about the difference between them. I am asking which is better.

Comment: Then you are asking an opinion based question. We don't question that on SO, all the opinion based questions gets deleted or locked e.g. "Is blue better then red?"

Comment: @HarounHajem that isn't totally true, That's like saying `String += String` rather then using a `StringBuilder` in a loop is opinion based. I am asking which is recommended way to setup views in. :)

Comment: Both setup the view but do it in different order. It's recommended in the document to use the latter for setting up states --> see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041206/android-fragment-oncreateview-vs-onactivitycreated

Comment: What's `Latter`?

Comment: It means the last example. Pointing to `onActivityCreated`

Comment: Okay so I don't really get that answer, What does the person mean by static views?

Comment: @Diffy, he meant by static view that the view which is displayed to the user is nothing but the inflated xml layout. No modification in coding or at runtime.

Comment: They don't hold a state, as the Google documentation describes.  It's recommended to restore state in onActivityCreated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can really use whatever you want, as long as it works.

However, I believe [onViewCreated()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onViewCreated(android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle)) is technically the "official" or recommended way to modify and reference your View after it's been created.

Comment: I see, I see some big applications set it inside `onCreateView` aswell. So I am gonna wait for more people to answer before I accept an answer.

Comment: Since no one answered over 11 days, I doubt anyone will soon. So i will just accept this